# I am trying to find the highest hourly pay for each city in mysql,while my subquery is working my whole query is not working

Tags: sql, mysql

### My subquery

```
select
  *,
  rank() over(partition by city order by hourly_pay desc)
from persons as a;
```

### My whole query

```
select *
from
(
  select
    *,
    rank() over(partition by city order by hourly_pay desc)
  from persons
) as b
where rank = 1;
```

The error I am getting in MySQL is error code 1064.

### Table

| ID | Name1 | dates | hourly_pay | city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mohit | 2016-07-07 | 12000 | nashik |
| 2 | Vish | 2018-07-07 | 11000 | gurgaon |
| 3 | rishi | 2019-07-07 | 12000 | raipur |
| 4 | kartik | 2020-08-18 | 25000 | jaipur |
| 5 | stephan | 2010-04-18 | 17000 | bilaspur |
| 6 | brook | 2010-02-02 | 19000 | delhi |
| 7 | arjun | 2009-05-05 | 42000 | gurgaon |
| 8 | shub | 2005-04-05 | 52000 | chennai |
| 9 | joe | 2010-05-05 | 32000 | panji |
| 10 | wade | 2001-04-05 | 49000 | chandigar |
| 11 | karti | 2008-04-05 | 72000 | singapore |
| 12 | arjun | 2007-05-05 | 32000 | gurgaon |
| 13 | mokshi | 2005-05-05 | 33000 | mumbai |
| 14 | hema | 2005-05-05 | 60000 | deradun |
| 15 | drake | 2001-01-01 | 20000 | delhi |

I've also tried with:

```
select *
from
(
  select
    *,
    rank() over(partition by city order by hourly_pay desc)
  from persons as a
) as b
where rank = 1;
```

I was expecting to get the rows where the pay is highest for each city and for cities with only 1 person, to just return that row alone from that city.

Comment: rank isn't an alias in your subquery, so the column in you where clause doesn't exist. you need to alias the rank() function since rank is a reserved word I'd use something like CityMaxRank and then where CityMaxRank=1

Answer (score 2):

The issue you're encountering is related to the use of the `rank` keyword directly in the `WHERE` clause. In MySQL, you need to alias the ranking column to use it in the `WHERE` clause of the outer query.

Here's how I'd modify your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *,
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY city ORDER BY hourly_pay DESC) AS ranking
  FROM persons
) AS b
WHERE b.ranking = 1;
```

I've named the ranking column as `my_rank` in the subquery. Then, in the outer query, I used `subquery.my_rank = 1` to filter the rows. This should get you the highest hourly pay for each city, and it should also fix the MySQL error code 1064 you've been seeing.

Answer (score 1):

If Rank() function doesn't work in the mysql version that you are using, try the below query:

```
select city,hourly_pay 
from (
    select p.city, p.hourly_pay,
       (select count(*)
        from persons p2
        where p2.city = p.city AND
              p2.hourly_pay >= p.hourly_pay
       ) as rank
from persons p) as t
where rank = 1;
```

Comment: In this query i have given it an alias -select *
from
(
  select
    *,
    rank() over(partition by city order by hourly_pay desc)
  from persons as rankd
) as b
where rank = 1;          This query also didnt work

Answer (score 1):

You can use a common table expression (CTE) to compute the ranks and then select the rows with rank=1 from the CTE.

```
WITH RankedPersons AS (
    SELECT *,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY city ORDER BY hourly_pay DESC) AS ranking
      FROM persons
)
SELECT *
  FROM RankedPersons
 WHERE ranking = 1;
```